# How to move axis label to opposite side in Altair horizontal bar chart

Tags: python, altair

My current chart looks like this:

[image: 1]

But I would like it to look like this with the percentages on the left side of the bar chart:

[image: 2]

What would be the easiest way to change this? Should I add more axis properties to my chart code? This is the code I have so far for the visualization:

```
bars = alt.Chart(percentages_df).mark_bar().encode(
    y=alt.Y('EMOJI',sort='-x'), 
    x=alt.X('PERCENT', axis=None)
)
    
    
text = bars.mark_text(
    align='left',
#    baseline='middle',
    dx=3
).encode(
    text=alt.Text('PERCENT_TEXT:N')
)

chart=(text+bars).configure_mark(
    color='#DAC352'
).configure_scale(
    bandPaddingInner = 0.1
).properties(
    width = 450,
    height = 180
).configure_view(
    strokeWidth = 0
)

chart
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the horizontal bar graph in the official reference as an example. First I moved the y-axis to the left and set the label value there to the position of the overall y-axis.

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

source = data.wheat()

bars = alt.Chart(source).mark_bar().encode(
    x='wheat:Q',
    y=alt.Y("year:O", axis=alt.Axis(ticks=False, domain=False, offset=25))
)

text = bars.mark_text(
    align='right',
    baseline='middle',
    dx=3
).encode(
    x=alt.value(-5),
    text='wheat:Q'
)

(bars + text).properties(height=900)
```

[image]